# Why I cannot use AND condition in the active record where function in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

```
MyBox.where(isClocked?: true) worked

MyBox.where(:OpenTime => beginMonth..endMonth ) worked

MyBox.where(isClocked?: true AND :OpenTime => beginMonth..endMonth ) not working
```

Why I cannot use `AND` in the 3rd sentence?

Comment: @igavriil That's completely irrelevant

Answer (score 3):

Because the *syntax* is wrong. The below will work :

```
MyBox.where(isClocked?: true, OpenTime: beginMonth..endMonth )
# Or
MyBox.where("isClocked? = ? AND OpenTime IN (?)", true, [*beginMonth..endMonth]  )
```

Check well defined Rails API of the [`#where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) method to know for ways you can apply with it.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `where` method is just a plain old Ruby method, and it cannot invent new syntaxes. In Ruby, it makes *no sense* to have an `and` between two hashes, which is effectively what you're trying to do:

```
{ key1: value1 } AND { key2: value2 } # syntax error
```

That is syntactically invalid, and even if you used the actual Ruby keyword `and` instead of the constant `AND`, it's *still* syntactically invalid Ruby:

```
{ key1: value1 } and { key2: value2 } # syntax error
```

You need to understand that ActiveRecord's `where` interface is limited in the syntaxes it can accept to those that Ruby can support. By default, if you want to provide two conditions, you simply pass two pairs of keys and values as ActiveRecord will always assume you want your conditions joined by `AND`s:

```
# ... where isClocked = true AND openTime > beginMonth AND openTime < endMonth
MyBox.where({isClocked?: true, OpenTime: beginMonth..endMonth})
```

You can also append multiple `.where` calls, and each set of conditions will be appended to the query as an `AND`:

```
MyBox.where({isClocked?: true).where(OpenTime: beginMonth..endMonth})
```

ActiveRecord, therefore, requires no special syntax for you to `AND` together conditions. However, if you need to `OR` together conditions, that requires you to manually write small snippets of SQL.